# asdf erlang fails to compile on macOS

Tags: macos, erlang, asdf-vm

I'm attempting to install erlang 22.3.4.18 on macOS 11.3.1 via asdf.

[The asdf plugin for erlang.](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang)

The OSX-specific instructions say to install `autoconf` and `wxmac` and I have. It also says the earliest version that will work is `22.3.1`. So as far as I know, this should work.

```
=== Running configure in /Users/<me>/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.3.4.18/otp_src_22.3.4.18/make ===
./configure '--enable-darwin-64bit' '--with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1' --disable-option-checking --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir="/Users/<me>/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.3.4.18/otp_src_22.3.4.18/make"
configure: error: cannot find required auxiliary files: install-sh config.guess config.sub
```

The log says it can't find required files: `install-sh config.guess config.sub`, but I have no idea what these are.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/erlang-otp-22-3-4-17-released/38748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link from [7stud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926143/7stud) and the answer on the elixir forum by [jerdew](https://elixirforum.com/u/jerdew), it compiled!

Anyone else who finds this answer, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/oriolgual/2f881fa3a151dd5f643f755ddcf2a0bc) has the solution.