# Elixir debugger crashes erlang on macOS

Tags: macos, debugging, erlang, elixir

`macOS Big Sur 11.3.1` `elixir 1.9.4` `erlang 22.0`

I am brand new to Elixir and I am trying to [run a debugger](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html#debugger) for the first time. I run my webserver's development environment with `iex -S mix` and get the interactive elixir prompt. Then I type `:debugger.start()` and receive an immense output and then erlang crashes.

This is a small snippet, but the actual output is huge.

```
 == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxTextValidator" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
```

I have to use the versions listed at the top of the post, the project is version locked. Does anyone have any insight into what is causing this? It may be related to [what I had to do to install erlang to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442905/asdf-erlang-fails-to-compile-on-macos). But I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the debugger, but I believe it relies on some of the same components as the observer.  I would recommend installing Elixir and Erlang via [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) -- that makes it easier to install specific versions.

Once you've got things installed, you can use homebrew to install `wxmac`

```
brew install wxmac
```

Then to your `mix.exs`, add `:observer, :wx` to your `extra_applications`, e.g.

```
extra_applications: [:logger, :observer, :wx]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I luckily did install erlang and elixir via asdf. I've made sure wxmac was installed and then added `:observer, :wx` like you asked, but no luck. Running :debugger.start() still produces the huge output and then a segmentation fault.