# Debugging Elixir streams

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir and I would like to learn how to debug [Streams](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.0.5/Stream.html) better.

It's common where I work to have operations performed on large datasets. This means that Streams are used heavily until the final operation, usually an `Enum.sum()`.

But this unfortunately means several calls look indecipherable as they are composed of several undocumented `Stream.map` functions. (a problem we are currently fixing). I would like to see the state of the data as it passes from stream to stream for debugging. How is this normally accomplished?

Example:

```
SomeModule.some_large_call_that_returns_a_stream()
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Enum.sum()
```

This is difficult to debug looking at the result, especially if `Enum.sum()` returns no value or 0.

Any suggestions? [And the debugger is currently unavailable to me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67623991/elixir-debugger-crashes-erlang-on-macos)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be enough to start with connecting `IO.inspect/2` to your pipeline?
ie:

```
SomeModule.some_large_call_that_returns_a_stream()
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Stream.map(&IO.inspect/1)
|> Stream.map(some_huge_hard_to_read_thing)
|> Enum.sum()
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that I know what to look for, I found it in similar places like [here](https://ropig.com/blog/ten-things-wish-knew-using-elixir/).